# pip does not answer when used within pyenv

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, macos-catalina, pyenv

I have installed `pyenv` and `pyenv-virtualenv` using Homebrew (I am working on macOS Catalina 10.15.6).

I am running a pyenv environment with python version 3.7.8.
If I activate my pyenv-virtualenv, and then try to run some `pip` commands, the commands do not return anything. I just see the blinking cursor on the next line. For example:

```
$ pip install -r requirements
```

or

```
$ pip list
```

Though, when calling just `pip`, I have the help menu.

The configuration seems ok:

```
$ which pip
```

returns

```
Users/marie/.pyenv/shims/pip
```

Outside the pyenv, pip works normally.

The problem seems to come from specific versions of Python and pip. Indeed, moving  to an older version of Python (Python 3.7.1) and pip (10.0.1) makes `pip` work fine.
But: Python 3.7.8 + pip 20 does not.

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Try `/Users/marie/.pyenv/shims/pip install --upgrade pip` or `/Users/marie/.pyenv/shims/python -m pip install --upgrade pip`.

Comment: This does not work either.

Answer (score 1):

Try reinstalling `pip`. This is probably relevant to your situation: [PyEnv Issue 1122 pyenv can't find pip](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1122)

Comment: Even trying `python -m pip uninstall pip` gets stuck and does not return anything.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing `pip` from scratch (from https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/7620#issuecomment-576653578).

```
curl -fL https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | /Users/marie/.pyenv/shims/python -
```

If `curl` is not found, you can try with `wget`:

```
wget -O- https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | /Users/marie/.pyenv/shims/python -
```

I don't know why this would be happening with virtualenv. I guess there could be some problem with the package on homebrew. You can `pip install virtualenv`.

Comment: Inside the venv, `python get-pip.py pip==19.3.1` does not respond either. (I am running python 3.7.8)